# PHP variable or JSON localization and how to retrieve them

Tags: php, mysql, json, localization

I want to implement localization. Once I get the language code, for example, `en`, what would be the best way to retrieve the text? For example:

```
en:
    welcome-text = "Hello!"
es:
    welcome-text = "Hola!"
```

also, what would be the most efficient and the fastest way? should i store them with php variables and get the text via php variables in an array or switch statement OR should i store them as json and get them via json?

Comment: Fastest way? Leverage existing code: https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n

Comment: Best way. Raad some tutorials and maybe even the manual, so you do it right the first time (usually the fastest way in the long run)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using some framework (most of them have translation functions and I really suggest you use one) I suggest you arrays as your translation files. It is a simple and fast way:

**en.php**

```
<?php return array(
    'Welcome' => 'Welcome',
    ...
);
```

**es.php**

```
<?php return array(
    'Welcome' => 'Holla',
    ...
);
```

**lang.php**

```
<?php
$mapping = require($_SESSION['user-lang-code'].'.php');

funciton _t($text)
{
   global $mapping;
   return isset($mapping[$text])?$mapping[$text]:$text;
}
```

Your page:

```
<?php 
require 'lang.php';

echo _t('Welcome');
```

Comment: what is the speed of this? would it be faster than json? please note I need the fastest and most efficient way.